# Indexing columns in a single text doc using Lucene

Tags: lucene

HI All,
          I am planning to index a single document, which has tab separated data as below:

```
      Name      ID     email     address
```

So when somebody searches for the 'Name' you should get his ID,email and address as the response. The same holds good for other columns as well. I am planning to use Lucene for this. But from whatever little I have read about Lucene, it talks about indexing multiple text docs. Can somebody guide me through a tutorial or link where i can build an index with my requirements.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just have each line be a "document."

This doesn't really sound like a good use for lucene though - why can't you just use a normal (relational) database?

Comment: Well.. the data is in this format.. Is treating every line as a document and the content within as the Field the only way out ? Also Xodarap, why do you say that it is not a good use of Lucene ? Even if we have the same in a relational DB, wouldn't Lucene beat it in performance ? Pretty new to Lucene, just trying to learn.. Thank you :)

Comment: @paypalcomp: Don't let the word "document" mislead you. You can think of each "document" as a single search result - you want each line to be a search result --> each line is a "document." wrt performance: Lucene is very good at free text search. So if you have large amounts of free text, lucene will be good. If you just want to search by a discrete value, a relational db will probably be faster, and it will certainly be easier to use.

Comment: @paypalcomp: also, if you are just starting with lucene, you may want to look into Solr instead. It is a wrapper around lucene which makes it much easier to use.

Comment: Great.. thanks you so much :) ill have a look at Solr.. thanks for your time again ..